# Parse ASMX XML web service result

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I'm getting this XML structure from an ASMX web service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <ArrayOfSecurityUser xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://sales.newsite.com/">
   <SecurityUser>
    <id>AAA1D75</id> 
    <code /> 
    <lastName>Thumb</lastName> 
    <firstName>Tom</firstName> 
    <middleInitial /> 
    </SecurityUser>
 </ArrayOfSecurityUser>
```

How do I parse it to get the full name using C# ASP.NET?

I have tried the following:

```
     XDocument x = XDocument.Load("GetUserInfo.xml");
     XNamespace ns = "http://sales.newsite.com/";
```

but I don't know how to parse it.

Comment: You seem to know it's an [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx). Have you tried reading the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

After that point all you have to do is read the elements and format the string such as:

```
string fullname = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
    x.Descendants(ns + "firstName").First().Value,
    x.Descendants(ns + "middleInitial").First().Value,
    x.Descendants(ns + "lastName").First().Value);
```

This is assuming there is only one SecurityUser. If there are multiple entries, instead you have to loop through instead of getting the first one.

Comment: How would you loop through multiple users?   Is there a better way using LINQ to do this and get specific users by id?

Comment: How would I do this if I call the webservice as an object like                         object userInfo = new UserService().GetUserInfo(userId);

Comment: Those are very broad and open-ended questions. I think you should research on those topics and ask here more specific questions